# ASP.NET Web Service returning code 500 when called from AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, web-services

I set up a AMSX Web Service and it works properly when accessing the URL:

```
public class ExpenseService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

[WebMethod]
    public void Get()
    {
        List<Expense> expenses = new List<Expense>();
        expenses.Add(new Expense(1, "Netflix", "Netflix", 20.00, new DateTime()));
        expenses.Add(new Expense(2, "Spotify", "Spotify", 14.90, new DateTime()));
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(expenses));      
    }
}
```

[image: Success]

However, when I make a GET from my AngularJS controller through $http:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "Pages/Home.html",
        controller: "homeController"
    })
});

app.controller("homeController", function ($http) {
var self = this;
$http.get("ExpenseService.asmx/Get")
     .then(function (response) {
         self.expenses = response.data;
     })
});
```

I receive this error on console:

[image: Console Error]

And if I click on the link from the error message (underlined on image above), I got the error on page as well:

[image: Error on page]

Just to remember: I can access the JSON when entering URL manually on browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]//add it and try again 
public class ExpenseService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

Comment: Did, still the same.